# Is there any way to store some fields from another table as an object into an entity?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity named Message.

It has some fields like: 
id,message and uid(as the user's id who send this message).

In order to render the sender's info, the user's public info (such as id and name) is needed when query the messages.In this way, I have to get the Message List first, and then, get the user's public info for each Message.

I wonder if there're any other easier ways to do this.

For example, can I store some fields from table User as an object called UserPublicInfo into Message?

And also, I don't want to join table User directly, because I didn't find any methods to hide the secret fields like password.

Comment: Why do you need to hide the password? Just don't include the password as a field in your entity. So you can map these two entities and solve your issue

Comment: @Abhijeet You are right. I didn't know it's possible to make multiple entities refer to the same table. It solves my problem nicely. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just knew that it's possible to make multiple entities refer to the same table. So my problem is solved.